# MonoDevelop reset F# interactive pad

Tags: f#, monodevelop, f#-interactive, fsi

Simple question: Is there a way to reset the F# interactive pad in MonoDevelop (not clear it) so that it starts over with a fresh session? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no button for doing that (i.e. context menu item as in Visual Studio), but you can reset the session by typing the `#q` command:

```
> #q;;
Session termination detected. Press Enter to restart.
```

If you then pres "Enter", you'll get a fresh F# Interactive session. Also, if F# Interactive gets stuck in an infinite loop, there is no button to kill it (I think) but you can kill it from a task manager and then you can restart it using "Enter".

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer i was looking for.